# Или Python или Ansible или Deban\Ubuntu не могут узнать, что была установлена нужная python-библиотека

Tags: python, linux, json, администрирование, ansible

Есть роль на ansible внутри которой надо сделать запрос к json через `jmespath`. "На моей машине всё работает" до тех пор, пока код не переносится на чистую убунту (докер или вбокс - не важно). Там по-умолчанию нет ни `python-jmespath`, ни `python3-jmespath`, ни `pip install jmespath`. Логичный шаг - поставить через стандартные модули, что я и делаю, но проблема в том, что вываливает: `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "You need to install \"jmespath\" prior to running json_query filter"}`

НО! Сразу при повторном запуске - всё начинает работать.

Собственно вопрос: как питону\ансиблу\убунте рассказать "поищи эту библиотеку внимательнее"? Гуглил `PYTHONPATH`, но там ничего интересного после любого способа установки.

`ansible 2.9.12, Ubuntu 18.04.5`

Comment: а как именно Вы ставите эту библиотеку? прям с под своего скрипта?

Comment: В проде у меня установлено на управляющем компе и всё отлично пашет. Но чтобы тестить в докере\чистой виртуалке - и контроллер и целевая система - это localhost. Ставлю и через модуль `apt` и через `pip`. Ставлю и третьепитон и второпитон - результат одинаковый.

Comment: ещё раз, как именно происходит эта установка? просто руками в консоли через apt/pip или это делает сам скрипт. Если это делает сам скрипт, тогда описанное Вами поведение - логично.

Comment: @KoVadim, если я руками поставлю, а потом запущу роль, то тоже всё будет ок. Т.е. система в целом уже будет знать, что либа установлена. Если я это буду делать внутри роли, то собственно см. вопрос.

Comment: @KoVadim, https://github.com/don-rumata/ansible-role-install-nodejs/blob/master/tasks/install-dependencies.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл решение. Проблема в закешированных фактах Ansible на стороне управляющей стороны - именно поэтому перезагрузка хоста, который настраивался - не всегда приводила к желаемому результату.

Нужно сначала [почистить](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/meta_module.html#parameter-free_form) эти самые факты, а потом сделать [setup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/setup_module.html).

В общем, на момент написания ответа (20-03-2021) с `ansible 2.9.18` работает отлично (ставил на 7,8 centos, 18,20 ubuntu):

```yaml
- name: Install python3-pip 4 Linux
  when:
    - ansible_system == 'Linux'
  become: yes
  package:
    name:
      - python3-pip
    state: present
  register: python3_pip_installed_status

- name: Install jmespath 4 Linux
  when:
    - ansible_system == 'Linux'
  # become: yes
  pip:
    name:
      - jmespath
    state: present
    # Because python3-pip
    executable: pip3
  register: jmespath_linux_installed_status

- name: Clear gathered facts from all currently targeted hosts
  when:
    - (python3_pip_installed_status is changed)
      or (jmespath_linux_installed_status is changed)
  block:
    - meta: clear_facts
    - setup:
```