# Ansible. Обновление переменной hostvars

Tags: ansible

Если в процессе выполнения playbook'a изменить файл хоста в **host_vars** (т.е. добавить новую переменную), как затем получить эту переменную в **hostvars** в текущем выполнении playbook'a ?
При повторном запуске она появляется в **hostvars**.

Comment: Тебе наверное нужно чё-то типа такого: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1258515/191416

Comment: @donRumata, делал clear_facts и setup, не работает ( А можно как-то вручную изменить hostvars ?

Comment: Через `set_facts` тоже не пашет?

Comment: @donRumata, а через `set_fact` разве можно `hostvars` изменить?

Comment: Попробовал, не получилось. Странно, я думал, что можно.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39381374/5430535 не оно?